# java.nio.BufferUnderflowException while converting byte array to double

Tags: java, exception, double, arrays, bytebuffer

I need to convert a bytearray to double. I am using

```
double dvalue = ByteBuffer.wrap(value).getDouble();
```

But at the runtime I am getting BufferUnderflowException exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:498)
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getDouble(HeapByteBuffer.java:508)
    at Myclass.main(Myclass.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

What do I need to change here?

Comment: can you show us value declaration ? with some code.

Answer (score 16):

[`ByteBuffer#getDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getDouble%28%29) throws

```
 BufferUnderflowException - If there are fewer than eight bytes remaining in this buffer
```

So `value` must contain less than 8 bytes. A [`double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is a 64 bit, 8 bytes, data type.

Answer (score 5):

Your code be something like this :

```
byte [] value = { // values };
double dvalue = ByteBuffer.wrap(value).getDouble();
```

If it is then it should work.

And show us your data of `value` array.

from the oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getDouble%28%29) :

```
Throws: BufferUnderflowException - If there are fewer than eight bytes remaining in this buffer
```

In order to fix it, you need to make sure that the `ByteBuffer` has enough data in it in order to read a double `(8 bytes)`.

Look [Here](http://bethecoder.com/applications/articles/java/basics/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-double.html)'s a simple code to show what you want with input data and output.

Comment: I am fetching row from a HBase Table
byte [] row1 = Bytes.toBytes(rowid);
Get g = new Get(row1);
Result result = table.get(g);
byte[] value = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("columnfamily"), Bytes.toBytes("columnname"));

But when printing 
System.out.print(value.length);
I am getting 4

Answer (score 0):

for others who have this problem, you have to extend byte array to be at least 8 bytes, so you can do it using this approach:

```
byte [] bytes = { /* your values */ };
bytes = extendByteArray(bytes);

// create a ByteBuffer from the byte array
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);

// convert the ByteBuffer to a double value using IEEE754 standard
double result = buffer.getDouble();
```

and here is the function implementation:

```
public static byte[] extendByteArray(byte[] input) {
    int length = input.length;
    int newLength = Math.max(length, 8);
    byte[] output = new byte[newLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < newLength - length; i++) {
        output[i] = 0;
    }
    System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, newLength - length, length);

    return output;
}
```